# When can the length of a line be equal to a circular function?

Tags: trigonometry

So, I'm having a bit of trouble trying to grasp this concept. 
I understand that a circular function like cosine is a ratio of two sides of a triangle in reference to an angle, however, one of my problems is this:
Given that line BN is tangent to the Unit Circle at the Y-Axis and the line AT is tangent to the Unit Circle at the X-Axis, and P(coss,sins) is a point in quadrant one, prove that AT = tans

My first instinct was to say this:
AT is the line opposite of theta.
If O is the origin 
then tans = AT/OA
But that really doesn't help me-- tangent is a function that returns the ration of the opposite side and the adjacent side of a triangle, so how could that ratio ever have the same length of the line it's using -- unless the ratio was one to one?
I'm not really sure how I should even think about this problem... any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have a ratio of two sides, you say.  What if the length of one of the sides was one?  What would be the value of the ratio then?

Comment: in that event it would be one
Also in the event the arc length was PI/4
However, I don't know if that satisfies the proof

Comment: Well, no it wouldn't be one.  If I have a ratio $a/b$, and $b=1$, that does _not_ imply that $a/b=1$....

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread -- And now what you said makes perfect sense!
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

As far as a formal proof goes you should first prove triangles similar by AAA.  Then you set up the proportion.

$$\frac{sin(s)}{\cos(s)} = \frac{AT}{1}$$

Then it is easy to see that $AT = \tan(s)$.